# Please help me out with translating this Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, csv

Please help with translate this Python code
I am trying to figure out the meaning of this code and could not end up with a conclusion... does anybody know how this single line code is like when it is not single lined.

```
data = [columns.get_text().strip() for columns in column]
write.writerow(data)
```

I thought it is translated as the code below, but it showed different value..

```
for columns in column:
        data = columns.get_text().strip()
        write.writerow(data)
```

please help...

Comment: You need to give the inputs as well so we can reproduce the output before posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of

```
data = [columns.get_text().strip() for columns in column]
write.writerow(data)
```

would be:

```
data = []
for columns in column:
    data.append(columns.get_text().strip())
write.writerow(data)
```